# Jquery on change function by value

Tags: html, jquery, onchange

i have this html code

```
<div class="toppings">
  <p>Would you like to add toppings?</p>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="pineapple" value="pizza1">Pineapple<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="onions" value="pizza1">Onions<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="sausage" value="pizza1">Sausage<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="pepperoni" value="pizza1">Pepperoni<br>
  <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="mushrooms" value="pizza1">Mushrooms<br>
</div>
```

How can I do it so that the user can only select 3 of those checkboxes by value? Because the wordpress plugin I use does not allow me to change any other parameters.And i have 5 different pizzas.

Comment: What does "by value" mean here?

Comment: "JavaScript Limit number of checkboxes selected" seems like a good search to run on Google,

Comment: By the way, you should use `"pizza1"` as the `name` for all your checkbox input elements, and use the topping names (e.g. "onions", "sausage", ...) as the `value` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
let checkedBoxes = 0;
$("div.toppings").find("input[value=pizza1]").click(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        if (checkedBoxes >= 3) {
            this.prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            checkedBoxes++;
        }
    } else {
        checkedBoxes--;
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that it's possible to do this without the variable in the higher scope, or having to maintain the count. Also be wary of using the `click` event on checkboxes, as it's possible to select them using the keyboard and some older browsers may not fire a `click` event in that case. See the answer linked in the duplicate for more details.